# virt-manager fails to connect to spice/vnc display when connecting with ssh keypair

Tags: ssh, vnc, kvm-virtualization

I have installed qemu/kvm on ubuntu 20.04 latest, and would like to manage the guests remotely with virt-manager.

I can successfully make a connection with:
virt-manager -c 'qemu+ssh://myqemuuser1@myip:myport/system?keyfile=XX_PATH_TO_PRIV_KEY_XX'

and see all the guests, and can configure them. However, when trying to open the display of a guest (VNC, or spice), I get:

```
SSH tunnel error output: USERNAME@IP: Permission denied (publickey).
```

when changing the sshd_config to allow password-based authentication, all works well again (VNC asks me 1 time for a password, spice ~8 times, but I know about that).

VNC is configured as "localhost only" and Port "auto".

*BTW: If I change this to "listen to all interfaces", I get a "guest disconnected" after some time (instead of the SSH tunnel error output: USERNAME@IP: Permission denied (publickey).)*

/var/log/auth.log shows:

```
sshd[10383]: Connection closed by authenticating user myqemuuser1 XmyipX port XmyportX [preauth]
```

there is no error shown in /var/log/syslog, and none in the guest logs in /var/log/libvirt/qemu/XXguestXX.log

I found a solution for proxmox about double-checking the format of keys in authorized_keys:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/connection-closed-by-ip-port-xxxx-preauth.46734/

So I double-checked the format of the file, and it looks normal to me (keypair created with
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa -f "/home/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa_SERVERNAME"):

ssh-rsa A....public-key-data...w== myqemuuser1@IP

I also made sure it is read-accessible by any user (other) all the way to /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys

I also copied it to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, yet the same error.

It seems the error message "Permission denied" is pretty correct, so probably for VNC/spice I have to copy the public key somewhere else, or make a symlink? I didn't find anything using google ...

my changes of /etc/ssh/sshd_config from the default are:

```
Port XcustomX
PermitRootLogin no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

(I tried virt-viewer along the way as well, but this didn't work either)

I had a look at the virt-manager debug log at ~/.cache/virt-manager/virt-manager.log:

1. working (password authentication enabled):

```
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:27 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (xmleditor:12) Using GtkSource 4
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:27 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (serialcon:17) Using VTE API 2.91
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:28 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (vmwindow:177) Showing VM details: <vmmDomain name=XguestnameX id=0x7fcf510bc3c0>
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:28 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (engine:391) window counter incremented to 2
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:28 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (console:715) Starting connect process for proto=vnc trans=ssh connhost=XqemuIPX connuser=XqemuUserX connport=XsshportX gaddr=127.0.0.1 gport=5900 gtlsport=None gsocket=None
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:28 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (sshtunnels:253) Pre-generated ssh command for ginfo: ssh -p XsshportX -l XqemuUserX XqemuIPX sh -c 'nc -q 2>&1 | grep "requires an argument" >/dev/null;if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then   CMD="nc -q 0 127.0.0.1 5900";else   CMD="nc 127.0.0.1 5900";fi;eval "$CMD";'
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:28 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (sshtunnels:277) Generated tunnel fd=20 for viewer
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:28 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (sshtunnels:201) Opened tunnel PID=262803 ERRFD=18
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:53:35 virt-manager 262723] DEBUG (console:838) Viewer connected
```

There is not a single  google search result with some of the keywords ... and I think the only thing missing is some permissions/symlink to the public key on the server-side for VNC/spice to access?

2. not working (authentication only with public key):

```
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:12 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (xmleditor:12) Using GtkSource 4
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:12 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (serialcon:17) Using VTE API 2.91
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (vmwindow:177) Showing VM details: <vmmDomain name=XguestnameX id=0x7ffb1a0f71c0>
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (engine:391) window counter incremented to 2
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (console:715) Starting connect process for proto=vnc trans=ssh connhost=XqemuIPX connuser=XqemuUserX connport=XsshportX gaddr=127.0.0.1 gport=5900 gtlsport=None gsocket=None
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (sshtunnels:253) Pre-generated ssh command for ginfo: ssh -p XsshportX -l XqemuUserX XqemuIPX sh -c 'nc -q 2>&1 | grep "requires an argument" >/dev/null;if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then   CMD="nc -q 0 127.0.0.1 5900";else   CMD="nc 127.0.0.1 5900";fi;eval "$CMD";'
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (sshtunnels:277) Generated tunnel fd=20 for viewer
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (sshtunnels:201) Opened tunnel PID=260956 ERRFD=18
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (sshtunnels:154) Close tunnel PID=260956 ERRFD=18
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (console:829) Viewer disconnected
[Do, 03 Dez 2020 10:44:14 virt-manager 260859] DEBUG (console:821) SSH tunnel error output: XqemuUserX@XqemuIPX: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this today... i did the same thing using a custom keyfile:

```
virt-manager -c 'qemu+ssh://user@server:port/system?keyfile=~/.ssh/custom_private_key'
```

after debugging, i found out the the problem here is that the custom keyfile is not being used when connecting to the display...

so i made a few changes on the remote server and copied my default public key  (id_rsa.pub) to the authorized_keys file... and viola!!! i can now connect and connect to the display using just:

```
virt-manager -c 'qemu+ssh://user@server:port/system'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add remote machine info into `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remotebox
    Hostname a.b.c.d
    User someuser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/custom_key_name
```

and then connect with `virt-manager -c 'qemu+ssh://remotebox/system'`